Python Django Annotations over multiple relationships
I have a question On Django annotations. Here is my model:
class Asset(models.Model):
    security = models.ForeignKey(Security, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)


class Batch(models.Model):
    fk_asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)


class BatchPosition(models.Model):
    fk_batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=False)

In my view I would like to annotate the total Sum of Batchposition->quantity to the Asset
I tried things like
Asset.objects.annotate(Sum("batch")).annotate(Sum("batchposition__quantity"))

...but can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here? Is it finally possible to achieve this?

You don't need sum of batches of each asset.
To get sum of quantity of BatchPosition of each Batch on Asset you can follow relationship directly using '__'. So if we set related_name to batches on fk_asset in Batch model and batch_positions on fk_batch in BatchPosition model we can annotate sum like that:
Asset.objects.annotate(batch_positions_sum=Sum('batches__batch_positions__quantity'))

Looks like you could use some more materials regarding Django ORM DB aggregations
Django Aggregation

If you have downvoted my answer, please leave comment what could be improved because from what I have tested this answer is working correctly

Thank you for your answer. However if I try this I get the following error:
name 'batch_positions_sum' is not defined" ... I tried to change it to Asset.objects.annotate("batch_positions_sum",(Sum('batches__batch_positions__quantity')) but it is not working either

I did not down-vote it by the way :-) Appreciate your help

I progressed: there was a = missing and some field names were wrong. So I am now at:
assets = Asset.objects.annotate(         batch_positions_sum=(Sum("batch__batch_positions__quantity"))     )
However now the error is: Unsupported lookup 'batch_positions' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted. Stuck again :-)

I had to rewrite this query from another PC and I included typo, there was also not needed "(" try it, should work now, let me know

I got it to work by adding a related_name to the model of batch_positions
